# Sum multiple variables, while leaving out variables that have a particular value

Tags: spss

I'm using SPSS and hoping to create a new variable that houses the sum of a group of previous variables. The catch is: if any of the variables are recorded as "9" then I need to leave them out.

Is there a command that makes this relatively easy? I had thought of doing `DO IF`, but it seems like that would get extremely tedious with 6 variables as I'd have to code each possible instance unless I'm mistaken. If there is an easier way that I just haven't been able to find, I would be forever grateful!

This is what I'm thinking would need to be done, but could absolutely be wrong:

```
DO IF (var1<=4 AND var2<=4 AND var3<=4 AND var4<=4 AND var5<=4 AND var6<=4).
COMPUTE newvar=SUM(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6).
ELSE IF (var1<=4 AND var2<=4 AND var3<=4 AND var4<=4 AND var5<=4 AND var6=9).
COMPUTE newvar=SUM(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5).
/* And so on and so forth for each possible variation of the sum.
```

It's not that this didn't work, I'm just checking to see if there's an easier way before committing the time to it.

Comment: UPDATE: we ended up just recoding all of these into different variables, designating the value that we didn't want (the "9") as missing and then summing the new variables. Still curious if there's another way or if this is the best path.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some ways to make it shorter:

```
missing values var1 to var6(9).
compute newvar=sum(var1 to var6).
```

Now if you don't want to just mark value 9 as missing, but to get rid of it all together:

```
recode var1 to var6(9=sysmis).
compute newvar=sum(var1 to var6).
```

If you don't want to change anything in the data, you can go:

```
missing values var1 to var6(9).
compute newvar=sum(var1 to var6).
missing values var1 to var6().
```

If all those sulutions are problematic for you, here's the classicle loop solution:

```
compute newvar=0.
do repeat vr=var1 to var6.
   if vr<>9 newvar=newvar+vr.
end repeat.
exe.
```

Here's another solution just for fun:

```
count nines=var1 to var6(9).
compute newvar=sum(var1 to var6) - nines*9.
```